# Is a table without tr valid?

Tags: html, html-table

Is it valid HTML to omit the tr elements in a table if you have only a single row? If it isn't valid, do all current browsers interpret it as intended?

In other words, does this ...

```
<table>
     <td>column 1</td>
     <td>column 2</td>
</table>
```

... behave the same as this ...

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>column 1</td>
     <td>column 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

?

Comment: What's the reason behind such a question?

Comment: @Nimesh If you can't change the HTML but only the CSS and you want to use a table with single row (e.g. for a navigation menu), sometimes there is nothing you can use for "display: table-cell". Take for example a list with one UL tag and many LI tags where the UL alone isn't wrapped into an other element. The only possibility is to use "display: table" on the UL and "display: table-cell" on the LI elements. This seems to work so far in the browsers I tested.

Comment: How can you only change the CSS and not the HTML? Is it being generated dynamically by some application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not a valid HTML as per the Spec, modern web browsers don't behave strictly and give a more readable output to the users instead of junk which is sometimes the mistake of the developer (not pointing to you).

What exactly works and what not, cannot be determined. Also if some wrong code is parsed by the browsers currently does not ensure if will do the same in future versions too.

Check the below excerpt about **[Browser's Error Tolerance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Browsers_error_tolerance) from HTMLRocks article 
[How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)**. The link has certain examples also about error corrections.

> Error handling is quite consistent in browsers, but amazingly enough
>   it hasn't been part of HTML specifications. Like bookmarking and
>   back/forward buttons it's just something that developed in browsers
>   over the years. There are known invalid HTML constructs repeated on
>   many sites, and the browsers try to fix them in a way conformant with
>   other browsers.
>
> The HTML5 specification does define some of these requirements.
>   (WebKit summarizes this nicely in the comment at the beginning of the
>   HTML parser class.)
>
> The parser parses tokenized input into the document, building up the
>   document tree. If the document is well-formed, parsing it is
>   straightforward.
>
> Unfortunately, we have to handle many HTML documents that are not
>   well-formed, so the parser has to be tolerant about errors.
>
> We have to take care of at least the following error conditions:
>
> 1. The element being added is explicitly forbidden inside some outer
>      tag. In this case we should close all tags up to the one which
>      forbids the element, and add it afterwards.
> 2. **We are not allowed to add the element directly. It could be that the
>      person writing the document forgot some tag in between (or that the
>      tag in between is optional). This could be the case with the
>      following tags: HTML HEAD BODY TBODY TR TD LI (did I forget any?).**
> 3. We want to add a block element inside an inline element. Close all
>      inline elements up to the next higher block element.
> 4. If this doesn't help, close elements until we are allowed to add the
>      element–or ignore the tag.

You can also check the w3c article [Validating your HTML > Different browsers interpret invalid HTML differently](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Validating_your_HTML#Different_browsers_interpret_invalid_HTML_differently)

> Valid HTML is the only contract you have with the browser
>   manufacturers. The HTML specification says how you should write it,
>   and how they should interpret your document
>
> ....
>
> None of the different browsers’ behaviours is incorrect; they’re all
>   trying to fill in the gaps of your incorrect code. The bottom line is,
>   avoid invalid markup if at all possible in your page!
>
> Note that HTML5 fixes this, as for the first time in the history of
>   HTML it defines how browsers should handle badly-formed markup. At the
>   time of writing however, support for this HTML5 error handling was not
>   widespread across browsers, so you can't yet rely on it.

Answer (score 4):

As per standard this is not valid, But **tbody, tr, td** Browsers ignore these tags and corresponding end tags.  But you can't write these tags outside the **table** tag.
Look following example for table creation: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_elements

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understood my question correctly. I clarified my example. If it isn't valid, do at least all the browsers interpret is as intended?

Comment: As per syntax this not valid but browsers ignores these tags so it works where I checked. Find given link.

Comment: Sorry, which tags exactly do browsers ignore here? In my example there is no "tr" which could be ignored since it is missing. The page you linked to does not answer my question because it's neither a w3c spec which would tell me whether my syntax is valid nor a test result which says the syntax without tr works in all browsers. In fact, it does at least in Firefox desktop, but there are many more browsers.